# fit image to viewport using flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to define this HTML/CSS layout:

```
+---------------------+
| navbar              |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|  h1                 |
|                     |
|  image              |  <= main-content
|                     |
|  p                  |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

Where the image is shrink if necessary to fit the viewport. I tried the following code, but the image set the height of `.main-content` while I want `.main-content` to set the height of the image. What's wrong?

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.main-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container mt-5 main-content">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <img
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg"
            />
            <p>some more text</p>
        </div>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This feels like a great place to try a grid. Something like `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto` should solve your issue and make it predictable.

Comment: You would have to set the height of the container to 100vh to restrict the hieght of the image.

Comment: @Paulie_D I think I need a heigth/max-heigth on .main-content, but 100vh is not the correct value. I would like to set it to the height computed by the flex-grow

Comment: @somethinghere will try with grid, but my problem is one-dimensional, so a two-dimensional tool seems overkill

Comment: same problem with grid

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to html/CSS. So I may be way off the mark here.

Based on my limited understanding, if the image is larger than the size of the parent, the parent will grow with the image. Hence the image is setting the height of .main-content. So to make the image fit the viewport two options come to mind.

1. Reduce the size of (Ex: [this image](https://data:image/jpeg;base64,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) is a small image and will fit most viewports)
2. Use 'calc' explicitly set the image height and width to always fit the viewport. For ex: in your example let's say the navbar, h1 and p take up 30% of the viewport. Then I would set the width and height the following way:

   ```
   img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(.70 * 100vh); //i.e. 70% of the viewport
    object-fit: cover; //(Depends on your goal. If you want then entire image, contain might work better.)
   }
   ```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.main-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

img {
    height: calc(.70 * 100vh);
    object-fit: cover; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container mt-5 main-content">
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <img
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg"
            />
            <p>some more text</p>
        </div>
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```